# Submenu with Flexbow Row in Flexbox Column: Submenu items not in same line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a UI with a fixed position left-aligned control panel (realized via flexbox with column direction) where sometimes a submenu is available for a given item in this flexbox. This submenu should be displayed to the left of the parent item. Now what I have this far looks promising:

```
.fixed-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 40.5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}
.submenu {
  height: 40.5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 41px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: calc(100vw);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hf5bts1a/15/

However, the submenu is not working correctly, as for some unexplainable reason two items are NOT displayed in a row, but instead again as columns (see the above fiddle; the lowest "button" has a submenu with 4 additional entries, see in red).

Comment: Hi Zahlii, please provide a [mcve] in the question itself. Also, I only see one submenu and it only has three entries, not four.

Comment: @TylerH well that is exactly the point. The submenu has four entries, but only three of them are displayed correctly in a line. The fourth actually jumps to the next line which it shouldn't. I updated the answer to more clearly reflect this and updated the fiddle.

Comment: I mean I only see three child elements in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was setting `min-width:40.5px`on the submenus buttons as well as adding `display:flex` to the button-groups inside a submenu.